# convert string cell in numbers with None values (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have 
A = ['x8' 'x7' 'None' 'None' 'x9.1']
I want to convert to
B = [8 7 0 0 9.1] (numbers)
Matlab code?

I have tried:

ind=strcmp(A,'None');
f2=A(ind==0); % the 'x_' terms
data=cellfun(@(x) x(2:end),f2,'UniformOutput',false); %remove the x for the numbers
f3 = sprintf('%s*', data{:});
N = sscanf(f3, '%f*'); %convert to numbers

It converts the 'x8' to 8, but I still have the 'None' values.
Any solution for everything at the same time?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post what you've tried.

Comment: A= [..] is not a cell

Comment: To follow on Daniel's comment, don't you have `A = {'x8' 'x7' 'None' 'None' 'x9.1'}`?

Comment: sorry; forget the cell mistake

Comment: @CarmenGarciaAparicio: In Matlab `A = ['x8' 'x7' 'None' 'None' 'x9.1']` is the same as `A = 'x8x7NoneNonex9.1'`. I would say your input data is already broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want like so:

To replace cells containing 'None' with 0, simply do this:

Find indices of those cells (as you have already done):

```
idx = strcmp(A,'None');
```

Then assign 0 to those indices, enclosed in {curly braces} since you put them into a cell array:

```
A(idx) = {0};
```

Now for the other entries, use `cellfun` as you did with the other indices, converting to doubles along the way:

```
A(~idx) = cellfun(@(x) str2double(x(2:end)),A(~idx),'uni',0)
```

Now `A` is the following cell array:

```
A = 

    [8]    [7]    [0]    [0]    [9.1000]
```

which you can convert to a numeric array since all the entries are numbers:

```
A =  cell2mat(A)

A =

    8.0000    7.0000         0         0    9.1000
```

Of course you can combine the last 2 steps into  single one.

Yay!

Comment: thanks!! i am not familiar to cells and i was using () instead of {}

Comment: Great! If the answer helped and you don't need further help would you mind clicking the green checkmark to mark it as accepted? Thanks!